# Deducing a template parameter from a constexpr constructor parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I have a string formatting function that is intended to only accept a string literal as the format string. I'd like to count the number of format placeholders at compile time and static assert that the placeholder count matches the argument count. Currently, I'm doing that with a macro, but it ruins overload resolution which I need to keep.

So, I'm attempting to pass the placeholder count as a non-type template parameter to my formatting function.

Currently, I have this

```cpp
template <u32 PlaceholderCount, u32 N, typename... Args>
b32
String_FormatImpl(String& string, const c8 (&format)[N], Args&&... args);

#define String_Format(string, format, ...) \
    String_FormatImpl<CountPlaceholders(format)>(string, format, __VA_ARGS__)
```

But what I'm looking for is something more like this

```cpp
template <int Count>
struct FormatLiteral
{
    const char* format;

    constexpr FormatLiteral(const char* format)
        : format(format)
    {}
};

FormatLiteral(const char* format) -> FormatLiteral<CountPlaceholders(format)>;

template <u32 PlaceholderCount, typename... Args>
b32
String_Format(String& string, FormatLiteral<PlaceholderCount> format, Args&&... args);
```

It this possible? It feels like constexpr constructors and template deduction guides might be a possible path, but I'm still wrapping my head around deduction guides.

Here's a minimal attempt: https://godbolt.org/z/Sjjtdo

Comment: A function parameter is never constexpr, even if the function is.

Comment: You are trying to create a compile-time string parameter. This is rather non-trivial. You may want to examine existing libraries that do that, such as libfmt.

Comment: gcc/clang has extension to handle UDL for C-string that allows compile-time string (via char sequence class).

Comment: It's not that I need the string at compile time, per se. Just a compile time property of the string. It's easy enough to forward to a template parameter as I did above. Really, I just want to get rid of the macro.